# NGINX - CURL extension installed but the system says it's missing

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, nginx, composer-php

I'm trying to update a Laravel project with composer, but the systems says:

```
Problem 1

- Installation request for netshell/paypal dev-master -> satisfiable by netshell/paypal[dev-master].
- netshell/paypal dev-master requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

The machine is:
Ubuntu 14.04
Nginx
PHP 5.6

I already did a lot of steps like:

- apt-get install curl
- apt-get install php-curl
- service php5-fpm restart
- service nginx restart

And still not working...

I also have the curl.ini file with:

```
; configuration for php CURL module
; priority=20
extension=curl.so
```

And my phpinfo says that curl is enabled:

[image]

What can i do more ?

Comment: Check my updated answer, I think it'll fix it. :)

Comment: Not working for you?

Comment: Still not working..  :|

Comment: did you run the `sudo ln -s` from my answer? Got any errors?

Comment: Yes, and got another error:

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/curl.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: What's the full path for your curl.ini, the one you quote in your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131589/discussion-between-yivi-and-ricardo-santos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`composer` and nginx use different PHP interpreters. You have `php-curl` enabled for **php-fpm**, but not for **php-cli**.

You can determine the actual configuration files used by **php-cli** by running `php --ini` (and you'll probably see that curl.ini is not in there)

Enable it with something like:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php/5.6/mods-available/curl.ini /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
```

**Attention**: the first parameter should be the actual location for your curl.ini file. So it could be also

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/curl.ini /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
```

If your run `php --info | grep curl -C 3` you'll see if curl is actually enabled for your php-cli installation.